# Multiprocessing and shared arrays not working in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I wanted to try creating a version of Conway's Game of Life in Python that could take advantage of multiple CPU cores to fully understand the multiprocessing library.

The output window (with pygame) shows the initial state correctly (evenly distributed alive and dead cells) but every single cell that the worker processes modify appears as alive (i couldn't find a way to determine whether it is actually set to 1 or to some other value because I'm bad at programming).

This is the code:

```
import math, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
from queue import Empty
import numpy as np

width = 1600
height = 900

task_size_width = 64
task_size_height = 64

def update_canvas(screen, data):
    colors = np.array([(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255)], dtype=np.uint8)
    color_map = colors[data.reshape((height, width))]
    color_surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(color_map.swapaxes(0, 1))
    screen.blit(color_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

def live_neighbors(a, x, y):
    neighbors = [(x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1), (x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x-1, y-1), (x, y-1), (x+1, y-1)]
    live = 0
    for x, y in neighbors:
        if 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height:
            if a[x + y * width] == 1:
                live += 1
    return live

def worker(queue, exit_flag, resume_exec, input_array_shared, output_array_shared, tasks_done):
    input_array = np.frombuffer(input_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)
    output_array = np.frombuffer(output_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)
    while not exit_flag.is_set():
        try:
            x, y = queue.get_nowait()
            for i in range(task_size_height):
                for j in range(task_size_width):
                    cx, cy = x * task_size_width + j, y * task_size_height + i
                    if 0 <= cx < width and 0 <= cy < height:
                        cell = cx + cy * width
                        live = live_neighbors(input_array, cx, cy)
                        if input_array[cell] == 1:
                            if live == 2 or live == 3:
                                output_array[cell] = 1
                            else:
                                output_array[cell] = 0
                        else:
                            if live == 3:
                                output_array[cell] = 1
                            else:
                                output_array[cell] = 0
            with tasks_done.get_lock():
                tasks_done.value += 1
        except Empty:
            resume_exec.wait()
    print("worker: exiting")
    exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, time, pygame
    pygame.init()

    exit_flag = multiprocessing.Event()

    print("setup: setting up shared data")
    tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()
    resume_exec = multiprocessing.Event()

    input_array_shared = RawArray("B", width * height)
    output_array_shared = RawArray("B", width * height)

    #input_array_shared = multiprocessing.Array("B", width * height)
    #output_array_shared = multiprocessing.Array("B", width * height)

    input_array = np.frombuffer(input_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)
    output_array = np.frombuffer(output_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)

    total_tasks = 0
    tasks_done = multiprocessing.Value("I", 0)
    tasks_done_copy = 0
    print("setup: done!\n")

    print("setup: creating and starting processes")
    process_count = 12#os.cpu_count()
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(tasks, exit_flag, resume_exec, input_array_shared, output_array_shared, tasks_done)) for _ in range(process_count)]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    print("setup: done!\n")

    time.sleep(0.1)

    print("setup: randomizing input state")
    input_array = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=width*height, dtype=np.uint8)
    print("setup: done!\n")

    print("window: initializing pygame")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Conway's Game of Life - CPUs: {process_count}")
    print("window: done!\n")

    print("window: first refresh")
    output_array[:] = input_array[:]
    update_canvas(screen, output_array)
    print("window: done!\n")

    print("setup: preparing task order")
    tasks_ = []
    tasks_w = math.ceil(width / task_size_width)
    tasks_h = math.ceil(height / task_size_height)
    tasks_cx = tasks_w // 2
    tasks_cy = tasks_h // 2
    tasks_x = tasks_cx
    tasks_y = tasks_cy
    d = 0
    while d <= max(tasks_w, tasks_h):
        d += 1
        if d == 1 and 0 <= tasks_x < tasks_w and 0 <= tasks_y < tasks_h:
            tasks_.append((tasks_x, tasks_y))
        for i in range(d):
            tasks_y -= 1
            if 0 <= tasks_x < tasks_w and 0 <= tasks_y < tasks_h:
                tasks_.append((tasks_x, tasks_y))
        for i in range(d):
            tasks_x -= 1
            if 0 <= tasks_x < tasks_w and 0 <= tasks_y < tasks_h:
                tasks_.append((tasks_x, tasks_y))
        d += 1
        for i in range(d):
            tasks_y += 1
            if 0 <= tasks_x < tasks_w and 0 <= tasks_y < tasks_h:
                tasks_.append((tasks_x, tasks_y))
        for i in range(d):
            tasks_x += 1
            if 0 <= tasks_x < tasks_w and 0 <= tasks_y < tasks_h:
                tasks_.append((tasks_x, tasks_y))
    print("setup: done!\n")

    while not exit_flag.is_set():
        # reset the output array to all 0
        print("mainloop: resetting output array")
        #output_array[:] = 0
        # refill the task queue and reset the task counter
        print("mainloop: resetting queue")
        total_tasks = 0
        for task in tasks_:
            tasks.put(task)
            total_tasks += 1
        tasks_done.value = 0
        tasks_done_copy = 0
        # resume execution on the processes
        print("mainloop: resuming processes")
        resume_exec.set()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        resume_exec.clear()
        # keep updating the pygame window until all tasks are done processing
        while tasks_done_copy < total_tasks and not exit_flag.is_set():
            #print("window: refresh")
            with tasks_done.get_lock():
                tasks_done_copy = tasks_done.value
            update_canvas(screen, output_array)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    resume_exec.set()
                    exit_flag.set()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        # an iteration has been computed, prepare for the next
        print("mainloop: preparing for next iteration\n")
        input_array[:] = output_array[:]
    print("main: waiting for workers to exit")
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    print("main: exiting")
    os.system("taskkill /f /im python.exe")
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import math, multiprocessing, time
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
import numpy as np

width = 1280
height = 720

def update_canvas(screen, data):
    colors = np.array([(255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255)], dtype=np.uint8)
    color_map = colors[data.reshape((height, width))]
    color_surface = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(color_map.swapaxes(0, 1))
    screen.blit(color_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

def worker(output_array_shared, _):
    output_array = np.frombuffer(output_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            output_array[x + y * width] = 0
            time.sleep(0.0001)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    output_array_shared = RawArray("B", width * height)
    output_array = np.frombuffer(output_array_shared, dtype=np.uint8, count=width*height)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    output_array[:] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=width*height, dtype=np.uint8)[:]

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(output_array_shared, 0))
    process.start()

    while True:
        update_canvas(screen, output_array)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

The issue is in the `output_array[cell] = ...` lines (I tested everything else and it works). I tried replacing `output_array[cell]` with `output_array_shared[cell]` but it didn't seem to make any difference.

I also tried replacing the RawArray objects with multiprocessing.Array objects and using `output_array_shared.get_obj()` in the `np.fromarray(...)` lines to be able to use locks, but that didn't solve the issue and only made my program slower.

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: using `input_array = np.random.randint(...)` in the main process instead of `input_array[:] = np.random.randint(...)[:]` breaks everything (because it replaces the `np.frombuffer(...)` instead of writing to it).
I don't know why that made a difference when writing to the output_array from the worker functions but it fixed all the issues with the code.